# What would be the most efficient codec for streaming long videos?

Tags: video, streaming

I have a video streaming website that has videos with lengths of around 3 hours, and video file sizes going between 2GB and 5GB for 720p and 1080p ~30fps H.264 AAC videos. There are some outliers (like files that are just a few minutes long and 100-300MB in size), so it should work fine with them too (even if not that efficient). The streaming is VOD (not live). I am running out of bandwidth and trying to encode the videos to minimize their file size.

To reduce bandwidth consumption, I am searching for an efficient codec that:

- would preserve as much quality of the original videos as possible while keeping the output file sizes as small as possible
- have wide compatibility with the latest internet browser versions for all popular OS (without any OS changes or browser settings needed).

Tre-encoding will be done using `ffmpeg` and Intel® Xeon® E-2276G CPU which comes with Intel® UHD Graphics P630 GPU.

So far, I've decided on AV1 but am not sure if it's the best choice given my context and am not sure about its browser compatibility. If AV1 is a good option, I would also want to use AV1 in fmp4 HLS streams if possible, so that I can also reuse the fmp4 segments for DASH. I am not sure if this is possible and how much web players (like video.js) could influence positively the browser compatibility.